# Can't load dataset after Visual Studio 2010 crash

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crash, strongly-typed-dataset

Here's my problem : Visual studio crashed while I was writing some code. After restarting, I got an error message "failed to load dataset because of the following error : column requires a valid datatype". I'm using 2 typed dataset and none of them want to open in the designer. I tried Restarting VS, rebooting computer, loading an old and working version of the project, open the project on another computer (using Team Foundation), deleting sources files and replace them with ones from an old and working version. Nothing worked.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I expect that the error pops up immediately because VS is trying to re-open the data set(s) that you had open prior to the crash.  Do the data sets have one or more columns that use a custom data type?  If so, can you successfully use the custom data type(s) in a simple class within the project - e.g. `CustomType customType1;` (assuming C#)?  I am wondering whether the columns' data type(s) simply isn't resolving, what you might find by setting aside data sets in particular for a quick reality check.

Comment: yes i am using a custom types on those data set, do you think that the crash prevent the dataset to get the type right ? Maybe if i can rebuild the whole porject without error that'll work, im not at work right now, ill let you know tommorow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this issue a while ago but I didn't find any solution online so here's my solution if someone ever needs it :

The issue come from the custom data type I use in one of the datatable. After the crash Visual studios was unable to recognize this type I created. This caused the Dataset to fail when loading (because of the unknown datatype) thus preventing me to rebuild the whole solution. Being unable to rebuild the solution prevented to compile my custom datatype and so on.

In order to solve this loop of fails, you can either :

- Clean the solution then build the project where the custom type is contained first. Then rebuild the whole solution.
- If the first method doesn't work, you can open the xml file of the dataset (right click on the file in the solution explorer > open with xml). Find
  the definition of the datatable containing the custom type and
  change the type of the column with something known (like `String`, `int`,
  pick the most appropriate). Save and reopen the dataset with designer
  (which should load now). You can now rebuild your whole project, go
  back in the designer, reassign the custom type to the column (the XML
  file will be re-generated) and you're done.